# Viewing multiple source files simultaneously using MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, monodevelop

Is the above possible? I often do it in VS (usually to have the test and test target visible together) using the flexible window docking system. Is there some way to achieve the same thing in MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure it's not possible. The editor does have a split screen mode ([as of Version 2.0](http://monodevelop.com/Download/MonoDevelop_2.0_Released)) but that only allows looking at multiple places in the current file.

Comment: Yeah, found that, not quite what I need. Will have to raise a feature request..using MD more and more now, will have to get involved.